# What information does Crashlytics collect from End Users?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm using Crashlytics in fabric.
I read privacy-policy.pdf to check privacy issues.
I found stored information includes device state information, unique device identifiers and so on.
I'd like to know what exact information is gathered for device state information and unique device identifier.

Comment: How are you able to identify the device model? Is it through an API exposed by the OS or is it through some other ID type or something else?

Answer (score 18):

Mike from Fabric here.

As referenced from [Crashlytics' site](http://try.crashlytics.com/security)

- An RFC-4122 UUID which permits us to deduplicate crashes.
- The timestamp of when the crash occurred.
- The app's bundle identifier and full version number.
- The device's operating system name and version number.
- A boolean indicating whether the device was jailbroken/rooted.
- The device's model name, CPU architecture, amount of RAM and disk space.
- The uint64 instruction pointer of every frame of every currently running thread.
- If available in the runtime, the plain-text method or function name containing each instruction pointer.
- If an exception was thrown, the plain-text class name and message value of the exception.
- If a fatal signal was raised, its name and integer code.
- For each binary image loaded into the application, it's name, UUID, byte size, and the uint64 base address at which it was loaded into RAM.
- A boolean indicating whether or not the app was in the background at the time it crashed.
- An integer value indicating the rotation of the screen at the time of crash.
- A boolean indicating whether the device's proximity sensor was triggered.
- The device's physical orientation (integer), current amount of RAM used, and current amount of disk space used.

Comment: The last bullet point: "Crashlytics uses a variety of identifiers to provide our services including" seems rather vague. Is there any more detail somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, what part is unclear - the identifiers listed after?

Comment: I was reading the word 'including' as indicating that this list of identifiers is not a complete list (i.e., these are just _some_ of the identifiers used). If this isn't a complete list, is there somewhere I can find all of the identifiers used. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, I see. Nope that's all the ids. The UUID mentioned at the beginning, Android ID, Android Advertising ID, and IDFA with the caveat mentioned. This is referenced in our docs on Android https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#identifiers-used and iOS https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html#identifiers-used.

Comment: @MikeBonnell,  Is it possible to restrict some of the above data being collected from end user device? Is it possible to configure only the allowed data to be collected?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following your question. You mention restricting data collection to the above set, but that's all we collect. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, among the above data collected, is it possible to restrict you from collecting certain data, which we consider as sensitive information, So that those data will not collected by the Crashlytics library.
is all above data mandatory for the crashlytics to work?

Comment: To give an example, if i want to restrict "The app's bundle identifier and full version number." collected by the library. How do i do that. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks, it's not possible to restrict that information. We need that information to handle crash reporting. We use the version number for a variety of things including detecting regressed issues and the bundle identifier is used when registering the app and associating crashes with it.

Comment: Got It, Thanks @MikeBonnell ...!

Comment: @MikeBonnell Can you please help to clarify why below details are being captured?
are we using for Dashboard ?
1. Device is jailbroken/rooted
2.  disk space of the device.
3. app's bundle identifier 
4.current amount of RAM used, and current amount of disk space used.

Comment: To help developers solve crashes or determine which crashes should be focused on. Some developers may not care to fix crashes where all devices are jailbroken. Disk space and ram usage are used to indicate that crashes may be caused by low memory or storage issues. The app bundle id is when registering the app and associating crashes with it.

Comment: Thank you so much, One last thing, How are you managing the data on the cloud, are you using any encryption to store all data related to crash?

Comment: Hey Jaber, this is documented in our data privacy: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/data-privacy.html#security-information "Fabric encrypts user data in transit and at-rest."

Comment: If there is a network problem (no network/fabric server down/unable to reach the server), will it make any problem(crash/hang/slowness/any popup)to the app?