# What data is being sent to the Fabric server ? [Fabric/Crashlytics]

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric.io, fabric-answers

We are working on a restricted Banking iOS/Android App and before integrating Fabric.io to our app we need to know what data will be sent to Fabric cloud

Our two main concerns are :

1. What is the data that will be sent to Fabric servers?
2. Is there a possibility that it can send any sensitive data like
   accessKey/username/password etc.
3. Does it have access to all the codes in our app?

Answer (score 1):

Mike from Fabric here. We collect just the minimum amount of data to provide you with high quality crash reporting. Many apps from the banking and financial industries use Crashlytics without any issue.

1) Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43612584/3975963) where another individual has asked the question.

2) No, unless you choose to record this information using custom keys or logs. I **strongly** recommend never logging this information.

3) We do not have access to any source code. A dSYM on iOS or mapping file on Android is uploaded in order for us to map back from the un-symbolicated crash report to an accurate crash.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, Fabric is an analytical tool that mainly sends crashes and events to its server. You can define events that you want to send. It doesn't access to your secret data